# new of ParameterizedType

Tags: java, reflection

If we have class as shown below:

```
Class ClassA {

}
```

To create an instance of classA using reflection, we either get reference to the default constructor and invoke it or call Class.forName(".ClassA").newInstance()

The question is how do I achive the same thing for a class that takes generic type.

Say I have a class

```
 public class ClassA<T> implements IClassA<String, T> {

        public ClassA(Class<T> clazz) {
            super(clazz, clazz.getSimpleName());
        }
    }
```

If we want to create an instance of type ClassA we do the following:

```
ClassA<ClassB> object = new ClassA<>(ClassB.class);
```

So, If I know fully qualified class names for ClassA and ClassB, will I be able to create an instance at runtime.

Thanks for your help in advance...

-Chandra

Comment: [As a possible answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373800/use-reflection-to-create-a-generic-parameterized-class-in-java)

Comment: Generics in Java happen at compile time. They will have no effect on runtime things like reflection. In particular, the class name is the same as without a generic type and an instance of `ClassA<X>` is indistiguishable from an instance of `ClassA<Y>`. If you need to refer to the generic type at runtime, the instance has to store an "evidence field".

Comment: If I know the class and generic type, is there a way to create the class instance...